# Web interface to versioning system

Tags: git, svn, versioning, cvs

Is there a versioning system with a great web interface so that it can basically be managed and used from a web browser?

The interface would need to function in the areas of committing new code and viewing/downloading previous commits.

Comment: committing via web? that would require the user to *upload* the modified code to this interface, doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: why would you want to use a browser interface?

Answer (score 5):

[GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) is kind of like the aforementioned Beanstalk, but for Git. I know it provides a great UI for viewing commits (and branches and tags and merges, etc.), but I don't know if you can commit from the UI.

Nobody has ever accused Git of being easy-to-use (no TortoiseGit, for example, although I hear it's coming), so you might be better off with SVN/BeanStalk.

Comment: +1 for the GitHub recommendation; but I can be accused of saying git is easy to use. There are a lot of features, but the basic commands for commiting, branching, getting diffs, merging changes are quite simple. The difficult part, IMHO, is getting one's head around its distributed nature.

Comment: My point here is that it's not as noob-friendly as TortoiseSVN. It's fairly easy to show a not-so-computer-savvy person that "commit" publishes your changes and "update" gets the latest changes off the server. With git, you're left with a command line, which many users are morbidly afraid of.

Comment: Yes, you can commit code through github.  (and I definitely accuse git of being very easy to use)  :)

Answer (score 4):

I use a Subversion server hosted by http://www.beanstalkapp.com/.  Beanstalk has a rich interface for navigating project source.  However, I don't use it for checking code in and out since it, like any web interface, commits/updates a single file at a time.  This would be very clumsy for a large project.

For commits/updates I use TortoiseSVN since it gives you (a) seamless interface to BeanStalk and (b) File Explorer integration.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike Miller said, I wouldn't be looking at the web interface to base your selection of a source control system.

[ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) has an excellent GUI, but it costs a fortune.

Most SCM systems now have web interfaces written by third parties that you can add. [WinCVS](http://www.wincvs.org/) for CVS, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for SVN and [git-gui](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for Git.

Concentrate on looking at what features the underlying SCM has and take it from there by layering the GUI over the top.

[VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe)? Hmmm. Not sure about that one. IMHO

Comment: TortoiseSVN is not a web interface, but a native Windows client application.

Answer (score 1):

There are several open source options for SVN and others, however I wouldn't use the existence of a web interface as a key decision point on a version control system. Most of them have a web interface available, but the key features are more core to the systems themselves.

Answer (score 1):

[MKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTC_Integrity) has a browser interface, but it is entirely unusable. It has a very poor UI and is entirely managed by JavaScript, so it is impossible to bookmark anything or send links to anything.

Further, it displays the entire tree as a single file listing with the full path to each item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [MKS](http://www.mks.com/) has a browser interface.

Answer (score 0):

The last version of [SourceSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) has a web interface. I've not used it though so I can't comment no how well it works.

References:

- *[How to: Set Up Database Access via Visual SourceSafe (Internet) Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230206(VS.80).aspx)*
- *[Visual SourceSafe 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/03/17/395048.aspx)*

Comment: anyone who mentions SS on this site is going to get nailed with down votes.  Sorry to say that.  everyone here apparently thinks git or svn are the second coming.

Comment: mmm, just because nobody likes VSS doesn't mean that it's not a valid answer/solution.